# Could somebody remind me an equation that I forgot?

Tags: calculus

Once in the forum I saw an equation, which is known to all mathematicians I guess. I havent noted down the equation and finally I forgot it. I am searching for a while to find it again but I couldnt find It although I spent alot of time. I will be happy if anybody could kindly remind me the equation. Here are the things which I remember about it:

$1$- The equation was about identification of a continuous function which was divided into infinitely many little intervals.

$2$- If I am not incorrect it was about the way of going from a discrete case to the continuous case.

$3$- The equation had at least a summation over all intervals. Perhaps integration and a limit as well. If there was a limit, then it was about when the infinitely many intervals' size was getting smaller and smaller.

This is all I remember at the moment. The formula should be very well known general formula.

Thanks in advance for any reminding.

Comment: yes this one, thanks alot. can you post as an answer?

Comment: Sure thing. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a [Riemann Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum). Here is one form of the formula
$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f\left(a+k\left[\frac{b-a}{n}\right]\right)\left[\frac{b-a}{n}\right]$$

The one above is called the left-riemann sum. There are many variations on this formula.

Answer (score 0):

$ \int_a^b f(x)\ dx = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=0}^nf\left(a + k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\frac{b-a}{n} $